# Error while building vopenlayers

Tags: svn, maven, openlayers, vaadin

I would like to fix some bugs in the vaadin openlayers Add-on. Hence, to build the source code, I followed the steps found in this link http://code.google.com/p/vopenlayers/wiki/DevelopingAndBuilding. However, I get this error when running the mvn install command:

```
[INFO] Building Unnamed - org.vaadin.vol:openlayers-wrapper:jar:1.2.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 146 resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/fakher/Desktop/vopenlayers-read-only/src/main/resources
[INFO] Copying 111 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/fakher/Desktop/vopenlayers-read-only/src/test/resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Compiling 37 source files to /home/fakher/Desktop/vopenlayers-read-only/target/test-classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-continuation/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-continuation-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-http-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-io-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-util-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-webapp-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-xml-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-servlets-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-client/7.2.2.v20101205/jetty-client-7.2.2.v20101205.jar; error in opening zip file
```

Who can help me to fix this problem?

PS: I am using ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need to use the `root` .m2 folder. Please do not use it. That helps avoiding security/permission related troubles.

I am guessing that you are doing mvn install with different user profile than root and your settings.xml is directing towards .m2 under `root` . The maven process is trying to extract some dependency via zip file which then encounter File permission issues.

Comment: No, I am doing it with the root profile. this is why mvn used automatically the root .m2 file. I exited the root and retried mvn install. So, It worked
thank you for the help